# CSS classes completion with CDN

Tags: javascript, html, css, webstorm

How to use the CSS classes auto completion on WebStorm for CSS files imported from CDN like this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: I don't think you can do so. "Intellisense" is possible only for css properties not for classes or Id's.

Comment: It seems that downloading external libraries is only possible for JavaScript files. I have submitted a feature request regarding external CSS: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24108

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only files located under your project root are used for completion/navigation/error highlighting, WebStorm doesn't use online resourses for types resolving. So you have to download the css and reference it using the relative URL to make the completion work

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. Only local css files are auto-completed. Feel free to request this feature at their issue tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues